# How to execute python script from a shell script using Nifi "ExecuteProcess" processor?

Tags: python, shell, apache-nifi

I am trying to execute a python script through a shell script using the "ExecuteProcess" processor. I could find shell command inside the shell script is working, but the python script is not getting executed. When I execute the shell script manually python script and shell command both are getting executed. What change should I make to execute the python script using the "ExecuteProcess" processor.
[image: Updated config]
[image: Process Flow]
[image: Shell Script]
[image: Manual Shell Execution]

Comment: What error do you have? Try to specify path to bash, set the current directory, ...

Comment: @daggett,  I don't get any error. my shell command is getting executed, but not the python script which I have in the same shell script.

Comment: what is the purpose of the current directory property? what value should I provide for that?  I have provided a value (/home/ubuntu/pythonscript/workingfolder) for the working directory now. Even now python script is not getting executed.

Comment: working directory - where to execute script. i think something with your script.

Comment: Hope there is no issue with script because when I execute the shell script manually it works perfectly. Both my shell and python commands are getting executed. I have attached screenshot for that also.

Comment: on screenshots you are starting it in `.../sourcefolder` - you should set the same for nifi property

Comment: Should I set sourcefolder path in working director property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217909/discussion-between-daggett-and-ganesh-kumar).

Comment: It worked after setting the working directory path with the path where the shell script is present. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after setting the working directory property with the path where the shell script is present.